# Discord.py embed color

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hey there I'm using a script to post from one server to another embed, but I need to change the colour from the forwarded embed (output) in this part from the code you also change the footer and all so I assume I have to set there the embed colour. I tried already a lot of methods like:

embed=discord.Embed(color=0xd10a07)

````
 if message.channel.id in channels_forward_embed:
            dest_channel_id = channels_forward_embed[message.channel.id]
            if message.embeds:
                embed = message.embeds[0]


                embed.set_footer(text="TEST | TEST", icon_url="pictureurl")
            else:
                return

            try:
                await self.cog.send_embed(dest_channel_id, embed)
            except:
                print('Error sending embed')
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.colour

> The colour code of the embed. Aliased to color as well. This can be
>   set during initialisation.

The embed color can only be set during initialisation. You cannot change the embed color after.

```
embed = message.embeds[0]
```

Here you are copying an embed from an existing embed. You then call `set_footer`. There is no equivalent command like `set_color`.

What you have to do is:

```
embed_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()
embed_dict['colour'] = 0xd10a07
embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(**embed_dict)
embed.set_footer(text="TEST | TEST", icon_url="pictureurl")
```

This initializes a new embed with the exact same title, description etc but with a modified color.

Note: I can not test it yet. No guarantee that my code is working but the concept of it should be working. Let me know if it works. If it is not working do a `print(embed_dict)` it should have a `color` set somewhere which you need to overwrite with a new value.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, sadly if i add your part to the script it gives me an error on line 80 [IMAGE](https://imgur.com/a/AaqK22m)

Comment: i deleted the whole stuff which was causing the error but now i get undefined error https://imgur.com/a/rz1GPs7

Comment: Your first screenshot. You didn't properly indent the code. Second one: You didn't delete everything.

Comment: yea just noticed that, but undefined hits different :D